# retrieve from the database is displayed in the form of currency

Tags: android, currency

the get string data that we retrieve from the database is displayed in the form of currency. I pass the adapter to list data

```
    Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
    NumberFormat formatRupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeID);
    holder.txt_price_capital.setText(formatRupiah.format(resultItem.getPriceCapital()));
```

and this is the error that is displayed

[image]

is there another way so that I change the data numbers to currency data.

Comment: What does currency data mean to you?

Comment: what is output form this statement `resultItem.getPriceCapital()`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q70m2x this it's on the adpater, 'resultItem.getPriceCapital()' 
take from the model class @NIKHIL MAURYA

Comment: for example from our country's currency, namely Rupiah / Rp.XXXXX
I took data from the database in the form of numbers @Prajwal W

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q70osw

Comment: No I meant what is the type of variable that is returned from the getPriceCapital() function? Is it a String or Double or Long or Int?

Comment: this float @NIKHIL MAURYA

Comment: It seems that getPriceCapital() returns String like “RP8.0000”, but NumberFormat.format() assumes that there will be a number (float or double or long etc.). You can, for example, pass Float.valueOf(getPriceCapital().substring(2)) instead. So result will be "Rp8" if this is what you want.

Comment: Change the datatype to String that will be a good fix